# Django sending values of object with foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin, parameter-passing

I have a app that have 2 models:

**Projecto Model's**

```html
class Projeto(models.Model):
   field1 = ........ 
   field2 = ........
```

**Aditamento Model's**

```html
class Aditamento(models.Model):

  processo = models.ForeignKey(Projet, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Projecto",related_name='ProcessoObjects')
  field1 = .....
  field2 = ....
```

**Projecto Admin**

```html
class AditamentoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    form = AditamentoForm
    model = Aditamento
    extra = 0
    max_num = 4


class ProjetoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AditamentoInline]
```

I can have 1 `projeto` with several `aditamento's` ( max:4)

Right now i want to send the field's of each `aditamento` to a page `html` to print.

when i open my object `project` i have 4 buttons , and when i click on of them , i want to send the fields of that `aditamento` corresponding that object i open.

[image]

So if i click in `3-aditamento` i will send the values of `aditamento` i create in third and so for all.

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean, "send"? Send what, to where?

Comment: i have a `view` that render to `html` the fields of `projeto`'model. i want  something like that to render fields of `aditamento`. But like is in the picture , if i want to render the `3-aditamento` , how can i get the field's?

Comment: Why can't you have a view for aditamento in exactly the same way?

Comment: Because 1 `projeto` can have several `aditamento`, when i click i the button  `3-aditamento` how can i know the third `adtiamento` to that `projeto`?

Comment: But the adtiamento has a primary key, just like any other model, so you can link directly to it. The projeto isn't relevant.

Comment: yes, I already understood what you meant, and gave me lights to solve the problem, at this moment I do only  this `Aditamento.objects.filter(processo=id)[0]` and I get the problem solved, thank you